# Single Linked List - simple approach

Tags: c++, object-oriented, c++11, linked-list, pointers

I am a student, trying to learn C++11 and data structures. I would like to ask you to to review my code. 
I have spent some time and analyse similar questions on Code Review and it gave me basic idea what I should pay attention to.

I have learnt about the rule of three, but I am not sure if my implementation is correct, especially = operator.

I would be grateful if someone more experienced than me could check it. I would like to improve my programming skills.

**EDIT:**
I didn't expect that `stdexcept` is required. On my local machine *it compiles without that library*... (Linux, eclipse, c++11 flag added). I am confused, sorry.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
class SingleLinkedList{
private:
    struct Node{
        T data;
        Node * next;
        Node() : next(nullptr) {}
        Node(const T num) : data(num), next(nullptr) {}
    };

private:
    Node * head;
    Node * tail;

public:
    SingleLinkedList();                                             // constructor
    ~SingleLinkedList();                                            // destructor
    SingleLinkedList(const SingleLinkedList &oldList);              // copy constructor
    SingleLinkedList& operator=(const SingleLinkedList &oldList);   // copy assignment operator

    void insert(T const& value);
    void displayList(std::ostream& stream = std::cout) const;
    void pushFront(T value);
    void pushBack(T value);
    void pushAtPosition(int position, T value);
    void popFront();
    void popBack();
    void popAtPosition(int position);
    int getLength();
    int getValue(int position);
    Node * search(T value);

};

template <typename T>
SingleLinkedList<T>::SingleLinkedList() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr){
    std::cout << "Constructor called..." << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
SingleLinkedList<T>::~SingleLinkedList(){
    std::cout << "Destructor called..." << std::endl;
    int index = 1;
    Node * temp = nullptr;
    while(head!=nullptr){
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
        //std::cout << "Node number: " << index << " destroyed" << std::endl;
        index++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
SingleLinkedList<T>::SingleLinkedList(const SingleLinkedList<T> &oldList){
    std::cout << "Copy constructor..." << std::endl;

    // is it necessary? my constructor by default initializes head and tail with nulls
    this->head = nullptr;
    this->tail = nullptr;

    Node * temp = nullptr;
    temp = oldList.head;

    while(temp!=nullptr){
        this->insert(temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

template <typename T>
SingleLinkedList<T>& SingleLinkedList<T>::operator=(const SingleLinkedList &oldList){
    std::cout << "Copy assignment operator..." << std::endl;

    if(this != &oldList){
        // delete previous content
        this->~SingleLinkedList();

        // copy all nodes from oldList to newList
        Node * temp = nullptr;
        temp = oldList.head;

        while(temp!=nullptr){
            this->insert(temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::insert(T const& value){
    Node * temp = new Node(value);
    //temp->data = value;
    //temp->next = nullptr;


    if(head==nullptr){
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
    else{
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::displayList(std::ostream& stream) const{
    Node * temp = nullptr;
    temp = head;

    while(temp!=nullptr){
        stream << temp->data << " -> ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    stream << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::pushFront(T value){
    Node * temp = new Node;
    temp->next = head;
    temp->data = value;
    head = temp;
}


template <typename T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::pushBack(T value){
    Node * temp = new Node;
    tail->next = temp;
    tail = temp;
    temp->data = value;
}

template <typename T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::pushAtPosition(int position, T value){
    Node * temp = new Node;
    Node * previous = nullptr;
    Node * current = nullptr;

    if(position < 1){
        std::cout << "Invalid index" << std::endl;
        throw std::out_of_range("Invalid index");
    }
    if(position > getLength()){
        std::cout << "Invalid index" << std::endl;
        throw std::out_of_range("Invalid index");
    }
    if(position == 1){
        pushFront(value);
        return;
    }

    if(position == getLength()){
        pushBack(value);
        return;
    }

    current = head;

    for(int i=1; i<position; i++){
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    previous->next = temp;
    temp->next = current;
    temp->data = value;
}

template <typename T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::popFront(){
    Node * temp = nullptr;
    temp = head;
    head = temp->next;
    delete temp;
}

template <typename T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::popBack(){
    Node * current = nullptr;
    Node * previous = nullptr;
    current = head;
    while(current->next != nullptr){
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    tail = previous;
    previous->next = nullptr;
    delete current;
}


template <typename T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::popAtPosition(int position){
    Node * previous = nullptr;
    Node * current = nullptr;

    if(position < 1){
        std::cout << "Invalid index" << std::endl;
        throw std::out_of_range("Invalid index");
    }
    if(position > getLength()){
        std::cout << "Invalid index" << std::endl;
        throw std::out_of_range("Invalid index");
    }
    if(position == 1){
        popFront();
        return;
    }

    if(position == getLength()){
        popBack();
        return;
    }

    current = head;
    for(int i=1; i<position; i++){
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    previous->next = current->next;
}

template <typename T>
int SingleLinkedList<T>::getLength(){
    Node * current = head;

    int len = 0;
    while(current != nullptr){
        len++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    //std::cout << "The list length is: " << len;
    return len;
}

template <typename T>
int SingleLinkedList<T>::getValue(int position){
    Node * current = head;

    if(position < 1){
        std::cout << "Invalid index" << std::endl;
        throw std::out_of_range("Invalid index");
    }
    if(position > getLength()){
        std::cout << "Invalid index" << std::endl;
        throw std::out_of_range("Invalid index");
    }
    for(int i=1; i<position; i++){
        current = current->next;
    }
    std::cout << "In index: " << position << ", the value is: " << current->data << "." << std::endl;
    return current->data;
}

template <typename T>
typename SingleLinkedList<T>::Node * SingleLinkedList<T>::search(T value){
    if(head==nullptr){
        return nullptr;
    }
    Node * current = head;

    while(current->next != nullptr){
        if(current->data == value)
            return current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    return nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SingleLinkedList<T>& list){
    list.displayList(os);
    return os;
}


int main(){

    SingleLinkedList<int> myList;
    myList.insert(10);
    myList.insert(20);
    myList.insert(30);

    // test of copy constructor
    SingleLinkedList<int> myList2(myList);
    myList2.insert(40);

    // test of copy assignment operator
    SingleLinkedList<int> myList3;
    myList3.insert(90);
    myList3 = myList2;
    myList3.insert(50);

    std::cout << "myList:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << myList;

    std::cout << "myList2:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << myList2;

    std::cout << "myList3:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << myList3;

    // standard operations
    std::cout << "-----------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "push front: "<< std::endl;
    myList.pushFront(5);
    myList.pushFront(2);
    std::cout << myList;

    std::cout << "push back: "<< std::endl;
    myList.pushBack(40);
    myList.pushBack(50);
    std::cout << myList;

    std::cout << "push at position: "<< std::endl;
    myList.pushAtPosition(7,4);
    std::cout << myList;

    std::cout << "pop front x2: "<< std::endl;
    myList.popFront();
    myList.popFront();
    std::cout << myList;

    std::cout << "pop back x2: "<< std::endl;
    myList.popBack();
    myList.popBack();
    std::cout << myList;

    //pop at position
    std::cout << "pop at position: "<< std::endl;
    myList.popAtPosition(2);
    std::cout << myList;

    //get value
    std::cout << "get value: "<< std::endl;
    myList.getValue(3);

    // search
    std::cout << "search: "<< std::endl;
    auto result = myList.search(30);
    std::cout << "Value: " << result->data << " found under " << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it currently work as intended?

Comment: Now - yes. On my local machine it **compiles without stdexcept**, I didn't have any idea that it doesn't work, sorry.

Comment: Even if your code does work the question about explaining code (I.e. #2) makes it off- topic.

Comment: Off-topic question was removed. Please open my question or comment what should I improve.

Comment: "but I am not sure if my implementation is correct, especially = operator." Does the code currently work as intended?

Comment: In my opinion code compiles and results are correct, I have only doubts if it is done in appropriate way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some good, a few things wrong.

I see you are nesting `Node` inside the class, which is good.  Most people start by making it a separate top-level item.

It is a problem though that the type `Node` is private, yet `search`, a public member, returns that!

---

You can use default initializers on the data members, and not have to list them in the constructors.

```
Node* head { nullptr };
Node* tail { nullptr };
   ⋮

SingleLinkedList() { cout << "Noisy class\n"; }
```

If you did not want the side-effect of logging creation, you could just say

SingleLinkedList() =default;

---

```
Node * search(T value);
```

This is not `const`?  Mistake, or does searching modify the tree?

---

You take `T` by value in all the functions.  What if `T` is a substantial type?  You want to normally take it by const reference, except for functions that will create a `Node`, in which case treat it as a “sink” parameter.

---

```
Node * temp = nullptr;
while(head!=nullptr){
    temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete temp;
}
```

[⧺C.149](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c149-use-unique_ptr-or-shared_ptr-to-avoid-forgetting-to-delete-objects-created-using-new) — no naked `new` or `delete`.

You should make the `next` member a `unique_ptr`, and then you don’t have to write this body at all.

But if you were writing a loop like this, you don’t need `temp` — use `std::exchange`.

---

```
template <typename T>
SingleLinkedList<T>::SingleLinkedList(const SingleLinkedList<T> &oldList){
    std::cout << "Copy constructor..." << std::endl;

    // is it necessary? my constructor by default initializes head and tail with nulls
    this->head = nullptr;
    this->tail = nullptr;

    Node * temp = nullptr;
    temp = oldList.head;

    while(temp!=nullptr){
        this->insert(temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

The style in C++ is to put the `*` or `&` with the *type*, not the identifier.  This is called out specifically near the beginning of Stroustrup’s first book, and is an intentional difference from C style.

You seem to be exploring different styles in this code; I see three different ways.

> is it necessary? my constructor by default initializes head and tail with nulls

The copy default constructor is not involved here, as this is a different constructor.  You should use initializer list, not assignment to the data members (as you had in the first constructor).

However, the change I suggested earlier — putting them on the data members themselves — works across all constructors.  So with that in place, you do not need to initialize them here.

You don’t write `this->` for access to your own members.

Declare a variable when you are ready to initialize it.  You *almost* had that here:

```
Node * temp = nullptr;
temp = oldList.head;
```

Why do you initialize it only to assign to it on the very next line?

```
Node* temp = oldList.head;
```

Don’t write explicit tests against `nullptr`.  Use the contextual conversion to `bool` as a more general truth value of objects.  This is more important when it comes to smart pointers.  The idiomatic thing to write is

```
while (temp) { ⋯
```

---

In your copy assignment operator:

```
    this->~SingleLinkedList();
```

**No**, never do that.  This destroys the object, and subsequent use of it is undefined behavior.  What you *can* do is have the destructor and the assignment operator both call a common helper function for tearing down the object.

The rest of it looks the same as the copy constructor.  So again, make a common helper.

---

```
Node * temp = new Node(value);
```

As mentioned before, don’t use naked `new`/`delete`.  So, if you used a `unique_ptr`, then this becomes `make_unique`.

The incoming `value` is a “sink” parameter.  That is, you will for certain be creating a new instance of that type in your fresh node.  So, optimize for that by taking it *by value* and moving it to the final location.

```
auto fresh = make_unique<Node>(std::move(value));
```

(The constructor for `Node` needs to continue moving)

---

```
void SingleLinkedList<T>::displayList(std::ostream& stream) const{
```

Don’t write a member for this!

Make a non-member that uses the general-use public abilities of the list to be traversed.

---

It seems that your primary access is by index position, treating it like a vector.  Imagine how slow that is if you go through each element in turn: each time you start over at the beginning and count one position farther!

You should present an **Iterator** that can be used like those in the standard library.

So, the `search` function is not necessary!  `std::find` should work on your list.

---

```
if(position < 1){
    std::cout << "Invalid index" << std::endl;
    throw std::out_of_range("Invalid index");
}
if(position > getLength()){
    std::cout << "Invalid index" << std::endl;
    throw std::out_of_range("Invalid index");
}
```

You already allocated `temp` so throwing will leak memory.  Put these preconditions *first*, before doing anything at all.

You are duplicating most of the content here.  Just write it as one test:

```
if (position<1 || position > getLength()) {
    std::cout << "Invalid index\n";
    raise_index_error();
}
```

A few other things to notice here:  Stop using `endl`.
Throwing generates a large amount of code, and is on the “cold” code path in a function you want to be inlined most of the time.  So always break that out into its own separate function.

---

Best of luck to you — keep up the good effort!

Comment: Thank you so much. I will study your answer and edit that comment.